# Visual Studio 2017 asp.net website publish only with necessary files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, publish, vs-web-site-project

I had to make some changes to a very old asp.net website project and now, when it comes to deploy the updated site I have found a weird? behavior that is VS "Publish Wizard" is uploading the whole set of files, including -for example- the .sln solution file (and probably others) that I know are not necessary in a production environment.

I tried to figure out why with no success, also wasn't able to find a "project properties" section where to configure "Publish" behavior.

If you look at the next url:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment

You'll see a "Package/Publish Web" and an option that is "Only files needed to run application" but this "Properties" menu is missing from my project -> right click.

What I expect is that "Publish" wizard only copies files needed to run website and not the whole set, but I'm expecting it picks them up automatically, I mean, I'm not looking for an option to exclude files, I don't know ev'ry file I have to exclude, instead I'd like the wizard to do it automatically.

Any help?

Thanks.